# is nrmse scale-dependent?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, inference, scikit-learn

Im trying to evaluate my regression models using a normalised version of the RMSE,

nrmse = rmse(y, y_pred)/rmse(y, y_mean) where y_mean is the array of the same len as y filled with the mean value of y. Intuitively, if nrmse<1 then the model scored better than a random model that would predict the mean value.

Is this metric scale-dependent? When I calculate this on the scaled data, I have different results on the unscaled data. The scaling is in [0,1], and the inverse transform of the predicted values is based on the statistics of the real scaled values.

Comment: Do you use linear regression model or some more advanced regression models?

Comment: I use more advanced models, but why is the relatable?

Comment: It's definitely is relatable! Linear regression with no intercept and standartized variables will provide you the same error as the linear regression with non-standartized variables. But no one can guarantee that in gradient boosting errors for standartized and non-standartized variables will be the same. Since the optimization framework is gradient descent, with standartized variables you can get another parameter estimates because gradient descent will finish in another minimum point compared to optimization without standartizing variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain why linear regression is scale invariant?